# Converting a search bar for a list to a search bar for select?

Tags: javascript, html, list, search

I currently have a search function in JavaScript designed for a `<ul><li></li></ul>`. 
However, I now converted the list to `<select><option></option></select>`. The select tag actually reads from text file and produces each selection as . 
Can someone help me with how I can convert this search function to work with  tag?
Here's the JS:

```
function mysearchFunction() {

    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        if (a) {
          txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        } else {
          txtValue = '';
        }
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } 
        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <input type="text" id="mysearchInput" onkeyup="mysearchFunction()" placeholder="Search for location..." title="Location">
    <label><select size=5 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();"></select>
    </label>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any html code?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want something like this:

```js
function mysearchFunction() {

  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("mysearchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myList");  // now our container is the select
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("option");  // and options are our items

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i]; // no need for querying the inner link element

    if (a) {
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    } else {
      txtValue = '';
    }
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";   // enable the matched
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none"; // disable the unmatched
    }
  }
}

function setPicture(){}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mysearchInput" onkeyup="mysearchFunction()" placeholder="Search for location..." title="Location">
  <select multiple size=5 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();">
  <option val="0">Dr.Emmet Brown</option>  
  <option val="1">Marty McFly</option>
  <option val="2">Clint Eastwood</option>
  <option val="3">Bonnie & Clyde</option>
  <option val="4">Calamity Jane</option>
  <option val="5">Billy the Kid</option>

  </select>
```